# Custom Filtering Kendo Grid Data on checked values in a second grid in the given date range (datepickers)

Tags: filter, grid, kendo-ui

I have data populated in a kendo grid gridDetails

and i have another grid grdFilter and two kendo datepickers..

I need to filter the data of gridDetails according to the checked rows and from/to date values selected in datepicker..
I need to filter gridDetails rows when the clicks on the button filter record after selecting date and values form gridFilter.

gridFilter:

```
   $("#gridFilter").kendoGrid({
   columns:
   [
   { field: 'CountriesName', title: 'Select', width:10,"template":
               "<input id='checkRow' type=\"checkbox\" />" },
   { field: 'CountriesName', title: 'Countries', width: 40}
   ] 
   })
```

gridDetails:

```
    $("#gridDtails").kendoGrid({
    columns:
    [

    { field: 'OrderDate', title: 'Activity Datetime'},
    { field: 'CountryName', title: 'Country', width: 150 },
    { field: 'OrderDetails', title: 'Order Type' },
    { field: 'OrderValue', title: 'Entry Price'},
    { field: 'OrderShipment', title: 'Shipment'}
    ] 
    )}
```

please guide me how do i get the checked values of gridFilter and Dates and then use them to filter gridDetails record and only show selected countries data of the given date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set `autobind` to `false` in your `gridDetails` initialization, this gives you time to specify what to load.
2. Then get the values from `gridFilter` and `datePicker`.
3. Build a `filter` condition and invoke `filter( condition )` on the `DataSource` of `gridDetails`.

The structure of the argument of `DataSource.filter` is like this:

```
{
    logic: "or",
    filters: [
        { field: "CountryName", operator: "eq", value: "Spain" },
        { field: "CountryName", operator: "startswith", value: "Bulg" }
    ]
}
```

Check in `DataSource` ([here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource) in the section about methods `filter` function.

Comment: With one value the filter is doing great how would i manage passing an array of possible selected countries to the filter

Comment: I'm afraid that you will have to iterate and build the array of filter conditions with one entry per country and set the `logic` to `or`.